# What is the inverse of str(b'foo\x00bar')?

Tags: python, python-3.x, character-encoding

I have a byte-string e.g. `b'foo\x00bar'` which was serialized into a string-string with str() e.g. `str(b'foo\x00bar')` resulting in `"b'foo\\x00bar'"`. How do I get the original byte-string?

So, given `"b'foo\\x00bar'"` how do I get `b'foo\x00bar'`?

Comment: `ast.literal_eval`?

Comment: @jonrsharpe that looks right, i get the correct result with `ast.literal_eval("b'foo\\x00bar'")`. Will you post that as an answer so i can upvote it?

Comment: ast.literal_eval is working with more complex examples as well

Comment: good find, thank you @jonrsharpe